# Configuring logstash with ssl and sending message to kafka(with ssl) topic

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, logstash

I have logstash-6.5.4 (with ssl), web and scheduler in my local (hostname: webbox) and kafka-2.0 (with ssl) on another (hostname: kafkabox).

I am not able to receive message in kafka topic when message is sent from logstash.

Neither error message is displayed not message is sent to kafka topic. I tried to import `logstash.crt` into kafka's truststore but it also didn't worked.

Created `logstash.crt` and `logstash.key` with below command.

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -batch -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/logstash/logstash.key -out /etc/logstash/logstash.crt
```

Imported the logstash.crt into kafka's truststore file also and tried.

```
keytool -import -alias logstash -file logstash.crt -keystore cacerts
```

Logstash conf file is given below...

```
input {
    tcp {
    host=>"0.0.0.0" 
    port=>5514 
    type=>"syslogType"
    ssl_enable=>true
    ssl_cert=>"/etc/logstash/logstash.crt"
    ssl_key=>"/etc/logstash/logstash.key"
    ssl_verify=>false
    }
}

filter {
}

output {
    kafka {
    bootstrap_servers=>"kafkabox:9093"
    codec=>"json_lines"
    topic_id=>"a_test"
    ssl_keystore_location=>"keystore file"
    ssl_keystore_password=>"changeit"
    ssl_key_password=>"changeit"
    ssl_truststore_location=>"truststore file"
    ssl_truststore_password=>"changeit"
    security_protocol=>"SSL"
    }
}
```

Expecting message is sent from logstash (with SSL) to kafka (with SSL).

**Java Code to connect to logstash which internally failing to send message to kafka topics (in ssl mode).**

```
public class LogstashClient {

    private static String message = "<86>Jun 25 14:32:25 webbox sshd[7517]: Failed password for root from 196.165.132.192 port 45691 ssh2";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        nonSSL();
        //SSL();
    }

    private static void SSL() throws Exception {

    // logstash.crt is directly imported into kafka's truststore
    // Below <<Client Truststore>> will also have logstash.crt imported for handshaking while connecting

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<<Client Truststore>>");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test1234");

        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("localhost", 5514);

    System.out.println("Handshaking...");
        socket.startHandshake();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        boolean checkError = printWriter.checkError();

        printWriter.println(message);
    }

    private static void nonSSL() throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5514);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        printWriter.println(message);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
RK,

Comment: How are you sending the messages to Logstash? Are you receiving the messages in Logstash?

Comment: Forwarding a message from syslog forwarder to logstash by doing ssh and giving wrong password. This was tested using wireshark tool where i can see the message.

Comment: Your input waits for a ssl connection, is your syslog forwarder configured to use the correct keys? Use a stdout output to test if you are receiving the messages, if this works, use a stdin input to test if you can output to kafka. Wireshark does not confirm that your pipeline works.

Comment: Syslog is not in a picture yet. Just given a try. 
I am trying to connect logstash (with SSL) using simple java code using SSLSocketFactory. Tested non-ssl and i am able to receive messages in kafka topics (which is in SSL) but not when logstash is in SSL mode.

Comment: Updated with java code.

Comment: If without SSL in the Logstash input you can receive messages in Kafka, using ssl output, your problem is in your input, the java code with SSL is not working. You can enable the DEBUG log in Logstash to see if it outputs anything when you try to run your Java code.

Comment: I re-created keystore and truststore and imported properly. This time it worked with SSL and also with Non-SSL. No code change. Might be the problem was with the certificate or some password of keystore/truststore. Any ways just testing end-to-end flow and will get back to you if found any issues.